# Cannot enter input in cgdb on Linux Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: c++, cgdb

Here is my very simple program that I am trying to debug with cgdb. Problem is once I get to the "scanf" line, it prompts for an input, but once I press enter after entering the input (2 in the example below) it seems to enter into an infinite loop. It works fine in gdb though.

```
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("%d\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the execution trace in terminal:

Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from test...done.

(gdb) start

Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x400585: file test.cpp, line 7.
Starting program: /home/Alex/Desktop/test

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at test.cpp:7

(gdb) next

2 (this is my input)

Infinite loop starts here.

Comment: @sfjac I should have mentioned. Yes it is on Ubuntu 14.04. I edited title.

Answer (score 2):

According to the info page of cgdb, you need to either:

- start the program on one terminal, and attach to it with CGDB from another terminal
- or pass arguments using the tty window

To invoke the tty window, hit 'T' in command mode (escape)

Extracted from the info page:

> Sending I/O to the program being debugged
>
> This technique is similar to getting in and out of "GDB mode".  The tty window is not
> visible by default.  This is because it is only needed if the user
> wishes to send data to the program being debugged. To display the tty
> window, hit `T' while in command mode.