# run c program with cgdb and blocked at getchar()

Tags: c, cgdb

My test.c file:

```
 #include<stdio.h> 
 int main() {
     int myChar;
     myChar = getchar();
     printf("You entered:  %c\n", myChar);
     return 0;
 }
```

---

compiled and run with `cgdb`:

```
$ gcc -g test.c
$ cgdb a.out
```

I input `start`, then input `n`, and I want to pass character 'A' to `getchar()`.

cgdb shows:

```
    (gdb) start
    Temporary breakpoint 1 at [34m0x1169[m: file [32mtest.c[m, line 3.
    Starting program: /home/test/code/a.out 

    Temporary breakpoint 1, [33mmain[m () at [32mtest.c[m:3
    3       int main(){

    (gdb) n
    6         myChar = getchar();
    (gdb) n
    A
```

I got blocked at the `getchar()` when I use `cgdb`.
I input 'A' and Enter, but it didn't continue.
I don't have this problem with `gdb`.

Comment: I believe you have to fire the `run` command. Just like `(gdb) run` and then give the input
`Starting program: a.out
a
You entered:  a
`

Comment: Actually I input `start` then `n`.  I tried your method but it didn't work.

Comment: Is it something that can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32707278/cannot-enter-input-in-cgdb-on-linux-ubuntu-14-04 ?